# Best way to convert comma separated string to integer array

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, integer

I have a comma separated string to convert to Integer array, I am using the below approach to do that, please suggest if there any simple way to do that.

```
Integer[] statusCodes = Arrays
        .stream(Arrays
                .stream(statusText.split(","))
                .map(String::trim)
                .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
                .toArray()
        )
        .boxed()
        .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: There is even no reason to use mapToInt, since that takes the Integer returned by valueOf() and unboxes it. Just use map(Integer::valueOf)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need outer stream. Also return type of [`Integer.valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) is already `Integer` (it is [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) which returns `int`) so you don't even need to `boxed()` it. Simply use `map` instead of `mapToInt`.

```
Integer[] array = Arrays.stream(" 1,2, 3, 4".split(","))
        .map(String::trim)
        .map(Integer::valueOf)
        .toArray(Integer[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Output: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Thank you for suggesting a better approach

Comment: @Pshemo but this will work only above api 24, what about below 24?

Comment: @RiddhiShankar Streams ware added to make writing code little easier, but it is still easy to rewrite it to use loops: `String[] tmp = " 1,2, 3, 4".split(","); int[] result = new int[tmp.length]; for (int i = 0; i<tmp.length; i++){result[i] = Integer.parseInt(tmp[i]);}`.

Answer (score 0):

Another version looks like follows:

```
Integer[] statusCodes = Stream.of(statusText.split(",")).map(Integer::valueOf).toArray(Integer[]::new);
```